# If Google Cloud Platform is configured with SAML on ADFS, can you integrate security with just AD using an LDAP connection?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ldap, saml, adfs

We have tried configuring SAML on ADFS and want to know if you can choose to to integrate with AD using an LDAP Connection as a simpler approach, or will this not be an option if SAML is in place? We haven't had much success as of yet, and wanted to get other experiences or opinions.

Answer (score 1):

If GCP has the ability to talk to a remote AD via LDAP (typically by installing a connector on the AD server or direct LDAP calls), that would be a possibility but it's not federation, you won't get claims and you won't get SSO.

To do this you need SAML.

There are two levels:

- Adding LDAP as an [identity store](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-fs/operations/configure-ad-fs-to-authenticate-users-stored-in-ldap-directories) if you need an LDAP that's not AD. Otherwise use AD out of the box.
- Setting up a SAML connection to ADFS by exchanging metadata and basing the claims rules on the identity store